# why is groovy skipping the each statement

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following controller action in grails to determine if an item is in my shopping cart

```
def itemInCart(){
    def cartHasItem = false
    def product = Product.findOrCreateByPartNumberAndColor(params.partNumber, params.color)
    def cart = shoppingCartItems()
    cart.each() { item ->
        if (item['partInfo']['partNumber'] == params.partNumber && item['partInfo']['color']==params.color){
            cartHasItem = true
        } 
    }
    render(cartHasItem)
}
```

I added an item to the cart

cart at the time of `cart.each()` is

```
[{partInfo={partNumber=69874, color=BLACK}, qty=1, price=16.99}]
```

params.partNumber = 69874

params.color = BLACK

The issue is that my code is completely skipping over the each() block.  debug hits `cart.each() { item ->` and then goes streight to render

Comment: What is the return type of `shoppingCartItems()` - is it possible that `cart` evaluates to groovy-false?

Comment: it returns ArrayList

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem, but you should change `each()` to `each`

Comment: @Dónal, actually, removing the parens *completely* fixes the problem. If you put it up as a solution I'll vote for it.

Comment: @BalRog cool, I've posted it as an answer

Comment: It makes no sense that removing those parens fixed the problem.  Are you really sure that is the case?

Comment: Are you sure that the closure isn't being executed? You mentioned "debug hits cart.each() { item -> and then goes streight to render".  If you are using a step debugger and do something like "step over" right after hitting the call to `cart.each()`, the next thing that your debugger should hit is the call to `render`.  The debugger should not stop on lines inside the closure unless you have breakpoints there.  The closure is executed in a different scope.

Comment: The closure is being passed as an argument to the `each` method and executed there, not really inside of the `itemInCart` method.  My guess is that everything is behaving as it should and that point is causing confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `any` instead of `each` here:

```
def cartHasItem = cart.any{ item ->
  item['partInfo']['partNumber'] == params.partNumber && item['partInfo']['color']==params.color
}
```

Comment: It's more efficient, since when it sees a match it sets the boolean to true and stops looping, but nothing ever sets the boolean to false. If there's a mix of N matches and M non-matches, `cartHasItem` will be set to true N times (and for large N it could end up being _very_ true), but it'll be the same result in either case

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on @Dónal's comment on the question, to find out why each() vs each is different.

I've never used object.each() {}, instead I always use this form:

```
cart.each { item ->
    // do work
}
```

However, I couldn't actually get each() to fail in this simple test:

```
def myfn() {
    def items = [1,2,3]
    def ret = false
    items.each() {item -> if (item == 2) { ret = true }}
    return ret
}
myfn()
==> true
```

I tried a more complicated version using a map to represent the data you are using, and a simple version just using

```
[[a:1, b:2, c:3]].each() { println it }
```

which always renders the item.

What version of groovy are you using?

I'm assuming your data is actually a list of maps here, your syntax for the item was more clojure, than groovy.